# Eclipse says jre does not support the current compiler level of 1.8 but it is set at 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed Eclipse mars with java JDK8 but was was having lots of problems with it so I uninstalled it changed back to JDK7 and now I'm getting a strange compiler error in a few of my projects. I noticed that when I went into, Windows->Preferences-> Java->Installed JREs, there is an error message at the top saying that "The selected JRE does not support the ...rent compiler compliance level of 1.8" but when I check the compiler compliance level its set to 1.7

Ok so I decided to try starting a new project and  when trying to build it a warning came up that my workspace compliance level was at level 1.8...changing the workspace fixed the problem. So new is it possible to change the workspace compliance level or should I just import my projects into a new workspace?

I tried importing into a new workspace,same problem. So I started new project in a new workspace, copyed and pasted the code in a voila it works! Very annoying if I have to do that for every class in every project I want.

Comment: clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunatly.

Comment: ok then in the buildpath section remove the jre and add it back (this will refresh cache )

Comment: also have you tried to launch eclipse with -clean ?

Comment: eclipse -clean no joy

Comment: ok tried to remove .metadata in your workspace and reimport the projects ?

Comment: I think you might be onto something with removing the .metadata but I'm not  sure how to go about it

Comment: before removeing all .metadata  try to remove .settings under `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings`

Comment: Found .metadata it was hidden directory. I first tried deleting .settings and when that din't work I deleted .metadata , that didn't work either. I restart eclispe - clean each time

Answer (score 14):

Check your compliance settings in:

> Preferences > Java > Compiler

Make sure the default is set to 1.7 as it may have defaulted to 1.8 after the initial install/run.

Also check project-specific compliance settings in:

> (Project) Properties > Java Compiler

Comment: Both those preferences are set to 1.7...there isn't even the option to pick 1.8

Comment: I checked both of these they are both set at 1.7

Answer (score 3):

I changed Windows ->Preference->Java->Installed JREs to jdk1.7.0_79 and right clicked the project, Properties ->Java Build Path, made sure that under Libraries tab, it is JRE System Library[JavaSE-1.7]. Clicked Project ->Clean. Right clicked the project again, Properties ->Java Compiler, checked Use compliance from execution environment 'JavaSE-1.7' on the 'Java Build Path'.Then it worked. [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you already changed all settings to 1.7 (both in the eclipse preferences and the project properties) check your project's build path. How? Easy, after you've imported your project, right-button click it and select Build path > Configure Build Path. Then, check if you have your JRE system library correctly set.

If even this is set up ok, I would say that you probably have some code that can only be compiled by jdk 8 and you're trying to use jdk7 compliance level, which eclipse warns you about. An example of this is using lambda functions, which can only be compiled with java 8 *as far as I know*.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Windows >> Preferences>>Compiler >> Unselect default
   compliance settings >> select the compiler compliance level to 1.8
2. This should reflect in generated .class files compatibility
   as 1.8 and source compatibility as 1.8 Step  Step
3. Apply it  Step
4. now click on apply and close
5. clean and build the project.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue with Mars on Pydev environment. Seems that Mars want java jre 1.7.0, so for me was work by copy inside(create if not avaiable) eclipse\jre\ folder  and copy the 1.7.0 version of jre inside

Comment: I unistalled Mars and installed Juno which is the one in the software manager in my Linux disto. I had it installed previously with now problems